# Javascript spin wheel arrow animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a spin wheel like this :

```
var img = document.querySelector('img');
img.addEventListener('click', onClick, false);


function onClick() {
    this.removeAttribute('style');
    var deg = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((1440 - 1080) + 1) + 1080);
    var css = '-webkit-transform: rotate(' + deg + 'deg);';
    this.setAttribute('style', css);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/imsy041/efum927n/8/

The question is how do I make an arrow/pointer that will flip when it touches the blue dots/pins around the corner? The result I'd like to achieve is similar to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gm9kftOieYI

Also, please have a look at this [thread](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/72170/how-simulate-the-return-effect-of-the-wheel-of-fortune-needle) on the gamedev community. I am by no means good in javascript... Is there an easier way than using physics engine?

Lim

Comment: You might want to first have a pointer that points to the correct item, the focus on having the pointer have animation that simulates flipping on the pins. No you don't need to have physics engine, you can at least approximate the pointer flipping by knowing the positions of the pins and angular velocity of the wheel. It really depends on how "good" you want it to look.

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek thank you for your reply, and how do i do that? as you can see, the wheel rotates at different velocity in a cubic bezier manner. and the degree that it rotates is different each time you spin

Comment: maybe this will help https://codepen.io/zadvorsky/pen/xzhBw

Comment: @RRR nice, but that is made by p2 physics engine, i tried to mess with his code but i cannot control the result/outcome. Even if I've modify it to onclick and give it the same velocity each time there are still many factors such as friction and current position etc that will affect the outcome.

Answer (score -1):

Oh my, that's way to complex to make a strater proyect.
I would recomend you to use **deg** to animate the flip.

In order to make the flip interact in a more realistic way: the blue dots the flip and the  wheel must be separate elements.